# Can't navigate in google maps activity it always spawns back to my current location

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-3

I am new to android development and was working on an app which requires google map activity.
Problem I am facing is that when I am trying to pan(or scroll) through the map I am immediately respawned to my current location which I set initially.
A little help would be wonderful as I am stuck at this point and unable to find a solution.
Here is the code:-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
    locationManager=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener=new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
            centerOnMap(location,"Your Location");
        }
    };

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
    }
    else{
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
        Location lastKnownLocation=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        centerOnMap(lastKnownLocation,"Your Location");
    }
}

public void centerOnMap(Location location,String address)
{
    LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title(address));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 15));
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull String[] permissions, @NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Every time you get a location update, the camera is moved to that location (in `centerOnMap` - invoked in `onLocationChanged`).  So no matter where you have scrolled map to it will return to your location on the next update.  If you need further help then state what behaviour you'd rather have instead.

Comment: as @Andy says your centerOnMap function is responsible for this. more specifically when your location is changed the centerOnMap function is called and the line mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 15));  change the map position to the current location. hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks @Andy for the reply, Actually what I was trying that when the user opens the Map Activity then his/her location is fetched and the marker is placed at that place and after that the user can pan(scroll) through the map and with a long press at a particular position the marker will be placed there(which I planned to do with onLongclickListener method) so if you can guide how to get around this scrolling issue it would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Abhra for the reply, Kindly look for the above comment and guide me if you can regarding the same.

Comment: if you don't need user location update then you can use FusedLocationProviderClient from com.google.android.gms:play-services-location instead of LocationManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one requirement that you likely have but not stated is:

> When the `lastLocation` becomes available and the user has
> not moved the map then center the map on the location.  If the
> user has already moved the map then do not center the map.  **In
> either case**, add a marker at the user's location.

Before getting too far along it must be noted that Google Maps provides a
feature similar to what you are trying to achieve, *though you'd still have to "move camera"*.  The marker is a blue-ball and not the typical marker.   See `myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)`.  That's it!  Do this when you have gotten map permissions.

But in the event you don't want to use that then here are the simple changes you need.

Remember that the `LocationManager` `getLastKnownLocation` can return
null if the device does not have one (yet).  So I'd recommend one small
change a bit unrelated - just let the location listener do all the work and get rid of this one special case:

```
// this is where you initially check permissions and have them.
else{
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
    // Here I removed the last location centering and let the
    // location listener always handle it.
}
```

So this opens the possibility
that the user could be interacting with map and finally the last location arrives.  I understand this to be the issue you are trying to address.

(As an aside, it seems to me you are mixing the use of the `android.location.LocationManager` with
the `FusedLocationProviderApi` (com.google.android.gms.location) so I couldn't get your
code to compile due to incompatible `LocationListener`s.
Unfortunately, Google Maps has two `LocationListener` classes so
to be certain  you'd have to include your imports to understand further.)

Anyways...

When the map is first ready (`onMapReady`) the camera of the map is
centered at `(0,0)`.  You can get the cameras target position (center)
at any time using `LatLng tgtCtr = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;`.

Oddly enough it is not straightforward to know whether the user has
interacted with the map *in any way*: scrolling events generate camera
changes while touch events generate a separate event.  Camera changes
cannot be used exclusively because your code or the user could just
zoom which is not moving the map.  You could go this route but
for the purposes of this answer, to keep things simple, the camera
target is used.

Declare a class instance variable (same area where you define `mMap`):

```
LatLng tgtCtr;
```

So in your `onMapReady` after assigning `mMap` do:

```
tgtCtr = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
```

So assume your code exists as you posted (it's pretty close) then these
changes may help:

```
// This change simply restricts centering of the map on location
// update to only when user has not moved the map (scrolled).

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
    LatLng currentCtr = mMap.getCamaraPosition().target;
    
    // This is not the ideal check since `double` comparisons 
    // should account for epsilon but in this case of (0,0) it should work.
    
    // Alternatively you could compute the distance of current
    // center to (0,0) and then use an epsilon: 
    //    see `com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween`.
    
    if (currentCtr.latitude == 0 && currentCtr.longitude == 0) {
        centerOnMap(location,"Your Location");
    }
}
```

It also seems like a good idea to save the marker which was added for user's
location - this is optional but may come in handy to prevent multiple markers
from being added at that one location:

```
// Define a class instance variable
Marker myLocMarker = nulll;

// and then in centerOnMap
public void centerOnMap(Location location, String address)
{
    // ... other code

    if (myLocMarker == null) {
        myLocMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title(address));
    }

    // ... more code
}
```

So really the only difficulty in this is figuring out "has the
user moved the map."  In this case, based on the initial requirement
you would not want to move the map.

Answer (score 1):

as you mention in comment section use FusedLocationProviderClient instead of LocationManager.
add    `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'` in app level gradle. and don't forget to add manifest permission for fine location.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);

    getLastLocation();
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(@NonNull LatLng latLng) {

            Location location = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            location.setLatitude(latLng.latitude);
            location.setLongitude(latLng.longitude);
            centerOnMap(location,"Your location");
        }
    });
}


@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private void getLastLocation() {
    if (checkPermissions()) {
        if (isLocationEnabled()) {
            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                    Location location = task.getResult();
                    if (location == null) {
                        requestNewLocationData();
                    } else {
                        centerOnMap(location,"Your Location");
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please turn on" + " your location...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } else {
        requestPermissions();
    }
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private void requestNewLocationData() {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(5);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(0);
    mLocationRequest.setNumUpdates(1);
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
}

private LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        Location mLastLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
        centerOnMap(mLastLocation,"Your Location");
    }
};

private boolean checkPermissions() {
    return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,   Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

private void requestPermissions() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
}

private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
}

public void centerOnMap(Location location,String address)
{
    LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    mMap.clear();
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title(address));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 15));
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        getLastLocation();
    }
}
```

}